# bootstrap col-md issues taking full width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I was trying to implement bootstrap in my project..But the col-md-3 is taking the full width of a container

The following is the code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home page </title>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4-offset-4">
       <div class="avatar">
         <h1>Special feature</h1>
       </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

  <div class="containe-fluid">
    <div class="row" >

      <div class="col-md-3" style="width:25%;">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0695/9547/products/Dell_Latitude_E4300_Laptop_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1421189962" width="300" height="300">
          <p>
                <a href="">Dell Latitude E4300 Refurbished Laptop<br>  $169
          </p>
          <button> Buy</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" style="width:25%;">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0695/9547/products/HP_255_Ubuntu_Laptop_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1421190061" width="300" height="300">
          <p>
            <a href="#">HP 255 UBUNTU</a><br>$229.00
          </p>
          <button> Buy</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" style="width:25%;">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0695/9547/products/621591-645880-800_large.jpeg?v=1421190099" width="300" height="300">
          <p>
            <a href="#">Lenovo Thinkpad B50</a><br>$229.00
          </p>
          <button>Buy</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" style="width:25%;">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0695/9547/products/618381-636132-800_large.jpeg?v=1421190057" width="300" height="300">
          <p>
                <a href="#">HP 255 Quad Core</a><br> $269.00
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to put the diffent products in one line and it is coming one below the other
Please help me am a newbie and am caught up.

Comment: Do not add `width` property if your using bootstrap `col-x` classes. `col-md-3` has its own `width` property.

Answer (score 6):

Avoid the use of inline `width: 25%` for the `col-x-*` classes. Also for supporting mobile width, Add `col-xs-6`.

`col-xs-` has *no minimum screen size*, so it makes sense to always include it. This is further explained in this [Boostrap Grid Sizes](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php) post. To save you some reading, the main bits of interest are:

- .col-xs-: Phones (<768px)
- .col-sm-: Tablets (≥768px)
- .col-md-: Desktops (≥992px)
- .col-lg-: Desktops (≥1200px)

To add offset, use `col-md-offset-4`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="avatar">
        <h1>Special feature</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0695/9547/products/Dell_Latitude_E4300_Laptop_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1421189962" width="300" height="300">
        <p>
          <a href="">Dell Latitude E4300 Refurbished Laptop<br>  $169
          </p>
          <button> Buy</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0695/9547/products/HP_255_Ubuntu_Laptop_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1421190061" width="300" height="300">
          <p>
            <a href="#">HP 255 UBUNTU</a>
          <br>$229.00
        </p>
        <button>Buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0695/9547/products/621591-645880-800_large.jpeg?v=1421190099" width="300" height="300">
        <p>
          <a href="#">Lenovo Thinkpad B50</a>
          <br>$229.00
        </p>
        <button>Buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0695/9547/products/618381-636132-800_large.jpeg?v=1421190057" width="300" height="300">
        <p>
          <a href="#">HP 255 Quad Core</a>
          <br>$269.00
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Plz add Bootstrap link to the page in the head section

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also, remove width=25% from the columns

also, change

```
<div class="containe-fluid">
```

to

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `width:25%` . The cause is when you use inline style it gets top priority on loading in html view page . And thus the whole bootstrap and inline style gets messed up .

Hope this will help your project get finished faster .

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you load bootstrap in your html file.

```
<head>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <!-- Optional theme -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <title>Home page </title>
</head>
```

I have tested your code with bootstrap css and it's working like it should.